# Unknown MySQL server host error in php

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

When i am connecting to mysql data base it showing

Could not connect: `Unknown MySQL server host 'servername/phpmyadmin/' (1) error`

code is

```
$con = mysql_connect("servername/phpmyadmin/","root","password");
```

how can i rectify it please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use "servername", not phpmyadmin directory.

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
```

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin is just a third party tool used for managing mysql databases. You have to specify just the server name.

```
$con = mysql_connect("servername","root","password");
```